# Non-component unit tests in React Native

Tags: unit-testing, react-native

I want to write some unit tests for a React Native/TypeScript app. The problem is that some of the libraries don't run under the development environment, like the 'AsyncStorage' or 'react-native-sqlite-2' ones.

The only thing I found in the Jest website is about mocking, but this is just a way to decouple the UI testing.

I was thinking of using some node.js library to simulate these libraries, loading the right ones depending on the environment.

Something like:

```
if(isDevelopment) {
    SQLiteDatabase = require("./sqlite_database_node").SQLiteDatabaseNode;
}
else {
    SQLiteDatabase = require("./sqlite_database_rn").SQLiteDatabaseRN;
}
```

Is this the right way to go about this problem? If yes, how do I import/require so that it works? If no, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run Jest or any unit test. The tests are running on the node environment. 
Hence when you try to access a module which has a native components/library (for example: Async Storage or SQLite ) the code will break in the test env.

To solve this issue Jest came up with module mocks. 
So what I do on my projects is that for any node_module that I use which uses a native module internally .. i create a global mock for it.

To do that you simply create a folder `__mocks__` on the root directory like so

```
.
├── README.md
├── __mocks__
│   ├── base-64.js
│   ├── react-native-animatable.js
│   ├── react-native-config.js
│   ├── react-native-device-info.js
│   ├── react-native-fetch-blob.js
│   ├── react-native-firebase.js
│   ├── react-native-google-analytics-bridge.js
│   ├── react-native-map-markerclustering.js
│   ├── react-native-maps.js
│   ├── react-native-simple-download-manager.js
│   ├── react-native-simple-toast.js
│   ├── react-native-splash-screen.js
│   ├── react-native-testfairy.js
│   ├── react-native-version-number.js
│   └── react-native.js
├── __tests__
│   └── index.test.js
├── app
│   ├── App.container.js
│   ├── __tests__
│   ├── assets
│   ├── components
│   ├── config
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── language
│   ├── pages
│   ├── redux
│   ├── routes
│   ├── themes
│   └── utils
├── app.json
├── circle.yml
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

And as an example lets look at

`__mocks__/react-native-firebase.js`

```
module.exports = {
  crash: () => ({
    setCrashCollectionEnabled: jest.fn()
  }),
  auth: () => ({
    signInAnonymously: jest.fn()
  }),
  database: () => ({
    ref: () => ({
      on: jest.fn()
    })
  }),
  config: () => ({
    fetch: jest.fn(),
    setDefaults: jest.fn(),
    getValue: jest.fn()
  }),
  messaging: jest.fn(() => ({
    requestPermissions: jest.fn(),
    subscribeToTopic: jest.fn(),
    getToken: jest.fn(Promise.resolve),
    onMessage: jest.fn(),
    getInitialNotification: jest.fn(Promise.resolve),
    onTokenRefresh: jest.fn()
  }))
};
```

or you maybe `__mocks__/react-native-device-info`

`const mockmod = jest.genMockFromModule('react-native-device-info');
module.exports = mockmod;`

the point is .. during the test env jest would automatically use these files when u do `require('react-native-device-info')`

As a result in test env u will have a mocked module running and in the app env you will have the actual node module.

Comment: if you have pure unit tests which don't touch code in a React Native component, why would you need to mock anything.  If someone is coding unit tests on JS modules that are independent of react native (such as a domain layer) that sits below inside your react native project one should be able to unit test that bare JS logic without any native reliance.  How would you set that up?  Right now if I try to run unit tests that are just functional tests not on react components I still get "Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null"

Comment: I agree, I have spent 2 weeks now evaluating react native and for all the benefit it allows at the component level actually building a large application that is properly tiered and testing those tiers in isolation is a complete pain. At this point I'm under the impression even large react native projects just end up mocking and only testing once they get to e2e tests, for large teams this may be ok but when trying to operate with 5-6 people having next to no assurance the lower tiers will work when in the react-native environment is crippling.